# Transposing / Reshaping based on variable but slightly different

Tags: python, r, sas, reshape, transpose

I have a table which I want to **Transpose** based on a variables. Although I know how to **Transpose** based on **one** variable in similar fashion , doing it in this style is not that I am aware of. Is it possible to do it in SAS / Python / R.

My Input Table

[image: Input]

The output which I want looks like This

[image: Output]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking: what exactly do you want your output to be, in terms of your input columns?

Comment: You are looking to `reshape`, not `transpose`.

Comment: Patrick, I just need the Month_Year column to sit on top of the three columns i.e. "Total_number_application","Total_application_one","Total_Application_two". Please let me know if it clarifies your question.

Comment: BondedDust. In SAS its usually called "Transpose" that's why I used that word. However which language might fulfill this request among python/ r / sas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `proc report` easily.  Starting with this code, then modify it for your needs style-wise.

```
proc report data=have nowd;
  columns application month_year,(total_number_applications tota_applications_one total_applications_two);
  define application/group;
  define month_year/across;
run;
```

Comment: I've never seen the bracket syntax on a PROC REPORT, interesting.

Comment: Kudos Joe, This is second new technique I am learning from you. the first one was **find** and second is using **(** and **)** in proc report.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **R** solution

If your data looks like this

```
dat <- data.frame(App = c(2,3), time = c("Sept", "Jan"),
                  Total  = c(2,1777),
                  total_one = c(1, 1521),
                  total_two = c(1, 256))

dat
#     App time Total total_one total_two
#  1   2 Sept     2         1         1
#  2   3  Jan  1777      1521       256
```

You can `reshape` it to `wide` format

```
reshape(dat, idvar = "App" , timevar="time" , direction="wide")


#    App Total.Sept total_one.Sept total_two.Sept Total.Jan total_one.Jan total_two.Jan
# 1   2          2              1              1        NA            NA            NA
# 2   3         NA             NA             NA      1777          1521           256
```

See `?reshape` for the details

Comment: Thanks user20650, however I am looking for something which can create two headers like in excel we do. Is it possible through **reshape**

Comment: With your data in this format (say a data.frame), R operates with variables as columns - hence only one column header per variable.

Answer (score 1):

`PROC TABULATE` is the best way of doing this easily...

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146759.htm

Something along the lines of...

```
proc tabulate data=mydata ;
  class APPLICATION MONTH_YEAR ;
  var TOTAL_: ;
  table APPLICATION, MONTH_YEAR ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the usage of **tabulate**. However I am getting **1** in all the columns and even after using stats like **N** in table its not getting solved. Any Hint.